# How to Stop and Resume Reading Files with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am attempting to scrape info from few hundred thousand files I am reading from disk and shove it into a SQLite database. I would like to be able to stop reading the files (i.e. crash or user interrupt) and have it pick up reading the files where it left off. Meaning don't start over with file number one every time. I've started working from a code sample that is helpful, but assumes you have sequentially numbered files delivered in sequential order. My issues:

1. I understand glob returns files arbitrarily
2. Files in my directory are similar in name not sequential

File names in directory might look like:

```
249959 Run Data Email D.eml
250000 Returned mail s.eml
250002 Warning could n.eml
```

Here is where I am code-wise:

```
cur.executescript('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MailSubject (id INTEGER UNIQUE, subject TEXT)''')

# Pick up where we left off
start = None
cur.execute('SELECT max(id) FROM MailSubject' )
try:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None :
        start = 0
    else:
        start = row[0]
except:
    start = 0

if start is None : start = 0

# Number user wants to grab
many = 0
# Number processed this go
count = 0
fail = 0
while True:
    if ( many < 1 ) :
        conn.commit()
        sval = input('How many messages:')
        if ( len(sval) < 1 ) : break
        many = int(sval)

    start = start + 1
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM MailSubject WHERE id=?', (start,) )
    try:
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row is not None : continue
    except:
        row = None

    many = many - 1
    print ("Many:", many)
# This is where you would define URL or file name to open
# below works for URL with sequential file names
# url = baseurl + str(start) + '/' + str(start + 1)

    text = "None"
    try:
        os.chdir("INBOX-200")
# This is how I open files now, no start / stop
# Files are not sequentially numbered
# Glob retrieves items in arbitrary order
    for file in glob.glob("*.eml"):
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print('')
     print('Program interrupted by user...')
     break
except:
     print('XXX File cannot be opened:', file)
     fail = fail + 1
     if fail > 5 : break
     break

# Must have succeed, increase qty processed this round
count = count + 1
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You need to persist in some way which files you have already processed so that you know which ones you can skip when starting the program the next time.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Understood in concept. This is much more straightforward when the files are named sequential and returned sequentially. Thus my problem.

Comment: But it's not that difficult either when they are not – in the simplest case you can just write the names of all files you have already processed as a list to a text file. Or to a table in the database.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for your comments. Even if I track which have been processed, how does it know which file to start back with if they are read arbitrarily (i.e. glob)?  I am not a professional programmer, so part of this must be lost on me.